# ispell on macOS shows limited spelling options

Tags: osx, ispell

I use Emacs both on Linux Mint and macOS. I use iSpell on both.
On Linux, when I check the region, I have around 20 options for a misspelled word; on macOS, the same word will only display 2 or 3 options.

I installed Emacs with brew and ispell as well. ispell-program-name is pointing at /opt/homebrew/bin/ispell which seems OK to me.

How do I get ispell to show the same number of words?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using `ispell` on Linux? It's often an "aliased" to the superior `aspell` or `hunspell`.

Comment: This is correct...! Looks the same, but on Linux I have aspell, and on the Mac ispell. Now I need to figure out why in Linux it runs aspell even though the command I have is ispell-region, which does not  exist on the Mac (just installed aspell from brew). Not sure how to get aspell to work on the Mac now, looking into it.

Comment: So no need to change anything. It's a bit odd, but when I'm checking ispell-program-name on the mac, it's already pointing to aspell. That's also what's going on in Linux.

Comment: Emacs just cascades through several options when setting the default for `ispell-program-name`, preferring `aspell` over `ispell`. You can see what's happening in `lisp/textmodes/ispell.el` or [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7ca1d782f5910d0c3978c6798a45c6854ec668c7/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el#L193-L206)